# load balancing algorithms - special example

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Let´s pretend i have two buildings where i can build different units in.
A building can only build one unit at the same time but has a fifo-queue of max 5 units, which will be built in sequence.
Every unit has a build-time.
I need to know, what´s the fastest solution to get my units as fast as possible, considering the units already in the build-queues of my buildings.
"Famous" algorithms like RoundRobin doesn´t work here, i think.

Are there any algorithms, which can solve this problem?

Comment: some data is missing: how much buildings do you have? what is the relationship between units? (must have 3 units of A before can start production of B for example) can you choose which assigment will go to each queue (since you said the units are already in queue)

Comment: let´s keep it very simple:

i have two buildings(later the amount of buildings will be variable).
no relationship between units.
every unit can be assigned to one of the two units.

Comment: Do you know the set of units to be built ahead of time or do they come in at "random" intervals and need to be assigned to a building as they come in?

Comment: @Lodger: and your goal is to decide which unit should be sent to which building, so the total time will be minimum? if so, all you intend to do is prevent idle time of one building, and one queue for both buildings (and when each building finishes working on a unit, he'll just pop from the queue) will give you just this.

Comment: @amit, I'm not sure this is right.  What if your single "to-do" queue contains units with build times of [2,2,5], and both factory buildings become available almost simultaneously? It's faster to give one [2,2] and the other one [5].  Your algorithm will give [2,5] and [2].    But maybe this idea works if you modify it so that the "to-do" queue is sorted longest to shortest.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question, is it like having to make 2 piles of different units that will be the closest in total construction time ? With the only constraint that piles cannot exceed 5 elements?

Comment: @Ashelly: I think you are right, I thought at first that the units come at exponentional ratio (standard queue theory), from second reading this is not the case. :\

Comment: @Ashelly: your comment made me realize this is NPC problem, details in the answer. thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong if you take least common multiplier of machine times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reminds me a bit of starcraft :D

I would just add an integer to the building queue which represents the time it is busy.
Of course you have to update this variable once per timeunit. (Timeunits are "s" here, for seconds)

So let's say we have a building and we are submitting 3 units, each take 5s to complete. Which will sum up to 15s total. We are in time = 0.
Then we have another building where we are submitting 2 units that need 6 timeunits to complete each.

So we can have a table like this:

```
Time 0 
Building 1, 3 units, 15s to complete.
Building 2, 2 units, 12s to complete.

Time 1
Building 1, 3 units, 14s to complete.
Building 2, 2 units, 12s to complete.
```

And we want to add another unit that takes 2s, we can simply loop through the selected buildings and pick the one with the lowest time to complete.
In this case this would be building 2. This would lead to Time2...

```
Time 2
Building 1, 3 units, 13s to complete
Building 2, 3 units, 11s+2s=13s to complete
```

...

```
Time 5
Building 1, 2 units, 10s to complete (5s are over, the first unit pops out)
Building 2, 3 units, 10s to complete
```

And so on.

Of course you have to take care of the upper boundaries in your production facilities. Like if a building has 5 elements, don't assign something and pick the next building that has the lowest time to complete.

I don't know if you can implement this easily with your engine, or if it even support some kind of timeunits.

This will just result in updating all production facilities once per timeunit, O(n) where n is the number of buildings that can produce something. If you are submitting a unit this will take O(1) assuming that you keep the selected buildings in a sorted order, lowest first - so just a first element lookup. In this case you have to resort the list after manipulating the units like cancelling or adding.

Otherwise amit's answer seem to be possible, too.

Comment: this might not be optimal (otherwise P=NP): for instance: {9,4,1,6}: as far as I understood your algorithm (also my suggested heuristic...) it will provide: {9},{4,1,6} while the optimal is {9,1},{4,6}...

Comment: would you please elaborate what is representing the brackets? It is not about partitioning, since you have already existing queues, you just want to assign a unit to the queue which has the lowest time to complete the production that it currently has.

Comment: Thomas: if you have 4 units to produce: taking 9,4,1,6 time units, the optimal solution would be: building1 produces 9,1; building2 produces 4,6, while your algorithm (and mine as well) will return building1 produces: 9 ; building2 produces 4,1,6

Comment: Yeah that is true, but a user in a game won't submit everything at once OR you can't predict that he will submit a unit with lesser amount of production time. So you have to assign the things to the best solution at the current time.

Comment: of course assuming that we don't really have the information- if this is round-based and a user submits every unit at once, your partitioning solution is better.

Comment: @Thomas: @Lodger's question: `I need to know, what´s the fastest solution to get my units as fast as possible, considering the units already in the build-queues of my buildings.` from what I understood, he's looking for a way to reorder his queues to produce the units as fast as possible, since they are already in queue!

Comment: So well I don't know, we have too few information on that. @Lodger should declare what he is exactly doing and wanting.

Comment: @Thomas: Starcraft is a really good example for this, i think ;)
In fact, i don´t want to reorder my building-queues right now. Yes, i am able to implement your solution with my engine. Thanks for it ;) But what i am looking for are 'famous' algorithm, which could handle that problem. I think [Multiprocessor-Scheduling-Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) - like in the answer above - should be good here?!

Comment: cool :D I don't think that multiprocessor-scheduling is the right way if it is realtime like you told. Since these are different problems. As you can see in your answers, it depends on the what information you have at a certain point of time. If you can't see what kind of units a player submits in the future, you're screwed. But we can give this algorithm a name and put a patent on that. Think starcraft does this the same way ;))

Comment: @Thomas, Lodger: If you don't have a list of units to build ahead of time, than this is the online version of [Job_shop_scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). See my answer for some updated ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is [NPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_polynomial-time_complete) problem (proof at the end of the answer) so your best hope to find ideal solution is trying all possibilities (this will be 2^n possibilities, where n is the number of tasks).

possible heuristic was suggested in comment (and improved in comments by AShelly): sort the tasks from biggest to smallest, and put them in one queue, every task can now take element from the queue when done. 

this is of course not always optimal, but I think will get good results for most cases.

**proof that the problem is NPC:**

let S={u|u is a unit need to be produced}. (S is the set containing all 'tasks')

**claim**: if there is a possible prefect split (both queues finish at the same time) it is optimal. let this time be HalfTime

this is true because if there was different optimal, at least one of the queues had to finish at t>HalfTime, and thus it is not optimal.

**proof**:
assume we had an algorithm `A` to produce the best solution at polynomial time, then we could solve the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) at polynomial time by the following algorithm:

```
1. run A on input
2. if the 2 queues finish exactly at HalfTIme - return True.
3. else: return False
```

this solution solves the partition problem because of the claim: if the partition exist, it will be returned by A, since it is optimal. all steps 1,2,3 run at polynomial time (1 for the assumption, 2 and 3 are trivial). so the algorithm we suggested solves partition problem at polynomial time. thus, our problem is NPC

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: ur proof is compelet;y wrong think we have two job for first macib takes 3 min and for second machine takes 2 min, so optimum way is one job for each machine there isn't any halftime.

Comment: @Saeed: I didn't claim there is HalfTime, I claimed: If there is HalfTime, the algorithm `A` MUST find it. and if it found something else, then there is no HalfTime. (which solves the partition problem)

Comment: @amit, But partition is different problem there are n arbitrary number but here we have 2 number arbitrary assigbed to n label.

Comment: @Saeed: I didn't understand your last comment, can you rephrase?

Comment: @Saeed: @Lodger's question: `I need to know, what´s the fastest solution to get my units as fast as possible, considering the units already in the build-queues of my buildings.` from what I understood, he's looking for a way to reorder his queues to produce the units as fast as possible, since they are already in queue! if there is a partition, it must be the best solution, and this is what the proof uses.

Comment: This is plain wrong. consider build times [1,1] for factory A and [5,5] for factory B. Suppose we wanted to build 4 of the first unit. It's faster to send them all to factory A and just ignore factory B. Your claim is ambiguous and false.

Comment: @Jean: I don't see nothing in the question that suggests build times are different from factory A and factory B for the same type of unit.

Comment: @Jean: also, my claim is `possible perfect split -> perfect split is optimal` and NOT `optimal -> perfect split`, your example don't fit the criteria for the claim, (because there is no perfect split, my claim doesn't say anything for this case, and thus is trivially true in here.) (and also, I don't see anywhere in the question about different times for factoryA and factoryB for the same type of unit).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple scheme:

Let U be the list of units you want to build, and F be the set of factories that can build them.  For each factory, track total time-til-complete; i.e. How long until the queue is completely empty.

- Sort U by decreasing time-to-build.  Maintain sort order when inserting new items
- At the start, or at the end of any time tick after a factory <strike>completes a unit</strike> runs out of work:

  - Make a ready list of all the factories with space in the queue

    - Sort the ready list  by increasing time-til-complete
    - Get the factory that will be done soonest
    - take the first item from U, add it to thact factory
    - Repeat until U is empty or all queues are full.

Googling "minimum makespan" may give you some leads into other solutions.  [This CMU lecture](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15854-f05/www/scribe/lec03.ps) has a nice overview.

It turns out that if you know the set of work ahead of time, this problem is exactly [Multiprocessor_scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling), which is NP-Complete. Apparently the algorithm I suggested is called "Longest Processing Time", and it will always give a result no longer than 4/3 of the optimal time.

If you don't know the jobs ahead of time, it is a case of online [Job-Shop Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling)

The paper ["The Power of Reordering for Online Minimum Makespan Scheduling"](http://eprints.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/568/1/04690993.pdf) says

> for many problems, including minimum
>   makespan scheduling, it is reasonable
>   to not only provide a lookahead to a
>   certain number of future jobs, but
>   additionally to allow the algorithm to
>   choose one of these jobs for
>   processing next and, therefore, to
>   reorder the input sequence.

Because you have a FIFO on each of your factories, you essentially do have the ability to buffer the incoming jobs, because you can hold them until a factory is completely idle, instead of trying to keeping all the FIFOs full at all times.

If I understand the paper correctly, the upshot of the scheme is to

1. Keep a fixed size buffer of incoming
   jobs. In general, the bigger the
   buffer, the closer to ideal
   scheduling you get.
2. Assign a weight *w* to each factory according to
   a given formula, which depends on
   buffer size.  In the case where
   buffer size = number factories +1, use weights of (2/3,1/3) for 2 factories; (5/11,4/11,2/11) for 3.
3. Once the buffer is full, whenever a new job arrives, you remove the job with the **least** time to build and assign it to a factory with a time-to-complete < *w*T* where *T* is total time-to-complete of all factories.
4. If there are no more incoming jobs, schedule the remainder of jobs in U using the first algorithm I gave.

The main problem in applying this to your situation is that you don't know when (if ever) that there will be no more incoming jobs.  But perhaps just replacing that condition with "if any factory is completely idle", and then restarting will give decent results.

Comment: I really think it will provide good heuristic for most cases, but like I said, it won't always be optimal (same example I gave to @Thomas will apply here)

Comment: @amit, I'm not sure why you think so.  In your case U is [9,4,1,6] which gets sorted to [9,6,4,1]. The queues F start at [][].  First pass through the algorithm gives [9][].  2nd Pass = [9][6].  3rd Pass = [9][6,4].  Last pass gives [9,1][4,6].

Comment: bad example, consider this one: [15,13,5,3,3] optimum is [15,5],[13,3,3] (max is 20) while the suggested solution will give [15,3],[13,5,3] or [15,3,3],[13,5] (max is 21).